# How to validate shell arguments?

Tags: shell, validation, command-line-arguments

I am trying to write a simple `sh` script that must be invoked with 2 arguments:

```
sh myscript.sh --user "some user" --fizz "buzz"
```

At the top of `myscript.sh` I have:

```
#!/bin/sh
# VALIDATION
# 1. Make sure there are 5 positional arguments (that $4 exists).
die () {
    echo >&2 "$@"
    exit 1
}

[ "$#" -eq 5 ] || die "5 arguments required, $# provided"

# 2. Make sure $1 is "-u" or "--user".
# 3. Make sure $3 is "-f" or "--fizz".
```

If validation fails, I'd like to print a simple usage message and then exit the script.

I *think* I have #1 correct (checking # of positional arguments), but have no clue how to implement #2 and #3. Ideas?

Comment: Is your question "How do I compare strings in a shell script?" or "How do I parse command line arguments?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# 2. Make sure $1 is "-u" or "--user".

if ! [ "$1" = -u -o "$1" = --user ]; then
    # Test failed. Send a message perhaps.
    exit 1
fi

# 3. Make sure $3 is "-f" or "--fizz".

if ! [ "$3" = -f -o "$3" = --fizz ]; then
    # Test failed. Send a message perhaps.
    exit 1
fi
```

Other forms for testing a variable for two possible possible values:

```
[ ! "$var" = value1 -a ! "$var" = value2 ]
[ ! "$var" = value1 ] && [ ! "$var" = value2 ]
! [ "$var" = value1 && ! [ "$var" = value2 ]
```

For Bash and similarly syntaxed shells:

```
! [[ $var = value1 || $var = value2 ]]
[[ ! $var = value1 || ! $var = value2 ]]
```

Besides using negated conditions with `if` blocks, you can also have positive conditions with `||`

```
true_condition || {
    # Failed. Send a message perhaps.
    exit 1
}

true_condition || exit 1
```

Of course `&&` on the other hand would apply with negated conditions.

Using case statements:

```
case "$var" in
value1|value2)
    # Valid.
    ;;
*)
    # Failed.
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Manually:

```
if [ -z "$1" ];then
fi

if [ -z "$2" ];then
fi

if [ -z "$3" ];then
fi
...
```

Or check getopt

```
while getopts "uf" OPTION
do
 case $OPTION in
     u)
         echo "-u"
         ;;
     f)
         echo "-f"
         ;;
 esac
done
```